# Relational Mapping between tables in different schema

Tags: grails, grails-orm, multi-tenant

Currently application is working on multiple schema in database, so we have a common schema that stores master tables whereas other schemas where we store client specific data.

So, specific scenario is like

(Below tables are for example purpose)

Master table for `AnimalType` which is resided in `common` schema whereas `Animal` table which is available on all client schema such as `schema1`, `schema2`...`schemaN`.

We are using `Grails` which default uses `Hibernate` so, relation is like

```
class AnimalType {
   String type

   static mapping = {
     datasources(['index'])
   }
}

class Animal {
   String name
   AniamlType animalType

}
```

So, when I start the application it shows below exception:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: An
>   association from the table animal refers to an unmapped class:
>   org.sample.AnimalType

What I understood from this is because, `Animal` is trying to refer to `AnimalType` in it's own schema, but `AnimalType` does not exists there.

So, basically I want to map `Animal` to `AnimalType` pointing to `common` schema.

Something like below with syntax in Grails

```
class Animal {
   String name

   @(POINTING TO COMMON SCHEMA)
   AnimalType animalType
}
```

Comment: Do you realy mean that you have a schema for each client?

Comment: Yes, as per business and legal requirements, we have new schema for each client.

Comment: Did my answer help? If it did not, did you solve the problem? An accepted answer will help those who search the problem later.

Comment: @Nathan: I'm sorry Nathan, but it did not solve my problem. At last I decided to manually store only id of an reference table without any foreign constraint.

Comment: Did that result in denormalization of the data?

Comment: No, but every time I need to create a new object from that id manually.

Answer (score 2):

In your `mapping` add something like this:

```
table name: "animal_type", schema: "common"
```

From the current [docs](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/table.html)

Comment: I have already defined a schema level to `AnimalType` as `datasources(['index'])`. But I want to reference 'AnimalType` in `Animal` to refer to `index` datasource which is `common`

Answer (score 1):

### Revised Answer

Hibernate is an abstracted layer on top of the database. Based on your `@(POINTING TO COMMON SCHEMA)` notation you may be coming from a Java background. Using the basic method below our group connects to dozens of schemata and multiple databases. Leverage the Grails domain classes to use convention over configuration when connecting to various schemata. See the Grails documentation on [mapping tables to domain classes](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/table.html). Let me try and explain by describing sample database schemata and domain class mappings.

Hopefully you are accessing the database through an application user. Let's call it ANIMAL_APP. ANIMAL_APP has access to the following tables:

- ANIMAL_TYPE (COMMON TABLE, all animals can access)
- TIGER (Only available to tigers)
- SNAKE (Only available to snakes)
- BEE (Only available to bees)

Each of these can have their own domain classes. They would also have their own controllers where individualized logic could be built in. BEEs fly and TIGERS do not which can be accounted for in separate controller actions.

AnimalType DOMAIN CLASS

```
class AnimalType{   
    //AnimalType properties  
    static mapping = {
        table 'ANIMAL_TYPE', schema: 'ANIMAL_APP'
        id column: 'id'
    }
}
```

TIGER DOMAIN CLASS //Could be any of the animals

```
class Tiger{
    Sting name
    String value
    static belongsTo = [animalType:AnimalType]

    static mapping = {
        table 'TIGER', schema: 'ANIMAL_APP'
        //Be aware that you could map to a different schema as follows
        //table TIGER, schema: 'TIGER_SCHEMA'
        id column: 'id'
    }
}
```

Once the classes are linked to each other, manage the table access where it should be managed, in the database. Create synonyms for the tables that the schema ANIMAL_APP can use for TIGER, SNAKE, and BEE. Grant the correct permissions to ANIMAL_APP for each of those tables.

Configure the data sources in `Config.groovy` and `DataSource.groovy`

`Config.groovy`
Configure the JNDI data source for each environment. Remember you are mapping to the database with ANIMAL_APP.

```
grails.naming.entries = [
        "jdbc/devanimalapp": [
                type: "javax.sql.DataSource", //required
                auth: "Container", // optional
                description: "Data source for Production", //optional
                driverClassName: "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver",
                url: "[replace with your databaseDriver]@[jndi location]",
                username: "ANIMAL_APP",
                password: "secret",
        ],
        "jdbc/prodanimalapp": [
                type: "javax.sql.DataSource", //required
                auth: "Container", // optional
                description: "Data source for Production", //optional
                driverClassName: "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver",
                url: "[replace with your databaseDriver]@[jndi location]",
                username: "ANIMAL_APP",
                password: "secret",
        ]
]
```

`DataSource.groovy` is then configured as follows. Remember this is a guideline and documentation can be found in the [Grails knowledge base](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/conf.html#dataSource).

```
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "validate" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            dialect = "[insert your database dialect]"
            jndiName = "java:comp/env/jdbc/devredapp"
        }
    }

    production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "validate" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            dialect = "[insert your database dialect]"
            jndiName = "java:comp/env/jdbc/prodanimalapp"
        }
    }
}
```

Mapping your domain classes this way will allow you to take advantage of Grails convention of configuration and be safe by only accessing the tables necessary through the ANIMAL_APP schema. Controlling permissions and synonyms in the ANIMAL_APP schema will allow you to connect to different schemata and even remote databases.

### *Original Answer below for transparency*

I am not sure I understand the question correctly but if you are trying to have the Animal Class inherit (see [Grails GORM Inheritence](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#inheritanceInGORM)) the AnimalType class you must declare the relationship for Hibernate.

```
class AnimalType{
    //some properties
    static hasMany = [animals:Animal, ...]
}

class Animal{
    String name
    String value
    static belongsTo = [animalType:AnimalType]
}
```

or

```
class Animal extends AnimalType{
    String animalName
}
```

If I have severly misunderstood your question please let me know and I will try again.

Comment: Yes, it seems you have misunderstood the question. I don't want to implement inheritation here, instead i want to reference AnimalType to Animal where AnimalType is in different schema and Animal is in different one.

Comment: Parth, I have updated my answer. Please read through the entire answer and let me know if it helps.